# Can't import Google Play Services library to project

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I am trying to import google play services into my project.

I am using Eclipse and went to **File->Import->Existing Android Code Into Workspace->Next->Browse** Browsed to:

```
C:\Users\Ami\android-sdks\extras\google\google_play_services
```

Here I saw `samples/map`, `samples/panorama`, and `samples/plus`. If I browse even deeper to:

```
C:\Users\Ami\android-sdks\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib
```

I get the error or `Select a directory to search for existing Android projects`, but there are no projects to select from the directory. I tried pressing the refresh button and nothing updated.

[image]

I have Google Play Services installed in the SDK manager

[image]

**I have tried:** cleaning and building my workspace. Closing and restarting Eclipse. Restarting my computer. Uninstalling Google Play Services and reinstalling it. Deleting the files from Windows Explorer and reinstalling them with Android SDK Manager. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: edit your question and remove "EDIT SOLVED" section and make it an answer (so you will be answering yourself). Then, as soon as SO will let you (2 days AFAIR), accept that answer to close this thread.

Comment: check this Link http://hmkcode.com/adding-google-play-services-library-to-your-android-app/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that the Android SDK Manager was saving to a different location than where I was looking. I had two Google Play Services in different files and under android-sdks was not the correct location. It was instead in my workspace under a file called: adt-bundle-windows. I think the file location changed due to installing a different version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

1. Copy your Google play services from `sdk->extras->google->googlePlay` services to a different location (i.e. Desktop)
2. Import it into Eclipse from there

Comment: In their instruction they said copy it to the workspace then import it, it is frustrating when it doesn't show up after following their words literally. They are wrong! You're right, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If some one still not able to find the google play serice project..... go to your sdk manager and download Google play API from Extra tags...Hope it help.... as i have the same issue