# Adding Google Play Services to my project

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to add Google Play Services to my project so I'm trying to follow step by step the guide google provides http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html but I don't know what to do when it says "To make the Google Play services APIs available to your app, you must reference the library project you created in step 4 of the installation instructions" because when I click on "installation instructions" it links me to the same page I'm already reading and there is no "step 4" unlike the instructions say. Does anyone know hot to proceed?

Comment: Eclipse or Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

try looking at this if you're using Eclipse

[Can't import Google Play Services library to project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793112/cant-import-google-play-services-library-to-project)

make sure you have the right location of where you downloaded google play services it's usually here in this path:

android-sdks/extras/google/google-play-services_lib

Answer (score 0):

This method is applicable for Eclipse. Import `<android-sdk-path>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/` into your workspace. And refer this project as a library project for your project.

Comment: I tried this method but when I select the google-play-services_lib it says "No projects are found to import"

Comment: you may have another project in your workspace already with the same name

Comment: yes I had one but even after deleting it and restarting eclipse it keeps giving me that message

Comment: Try with a new workspace and check whether the problem persists.

Comment: Yes the problem persists even with a new workspace :(

Comment: I tried to import it with : Android/Existing Android Code Into Workspace and it worked

Answer (score 0):

in eclipse :

Select the Project with Right click and then select Properties. now u go Android -> Library -> add . select google-play-services_lib .

obs: u have to import the google_play_services_lib from your sdk directory to your workspace!

directory : \sdk\extras\google\google_play_services.

please tell me if it worked.

Sorry for this horrible grammar(english isn't my native language).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've already solved my problem by importing the library from: Android/Existing Android Code Into Workspace

Comment: your welcome! If someone answered well you question, you should choice as right answer or give few points.

Comment: You just set the answer with the right answer, accepted answer or something like this. i'm never asked anything, i just answered hahaha.

You can use the top arrow for give few points or the bottom arrow to take away few.

Comment: Yes I knew that but my reputation isn't enough to do it

Answer (score 0):

1.Your workspace and the google-play-services lib project should be there in the same directory.

2.If your workspace in D:/ then your google-pay-services lib project files also needs to be in the same.

In your case this may work,

File - Import- Android - Excisting Android Code into Workspace then select your project, this will work.